# Problemas con sumatoria de consultas al integrar left join en mysql

Tags: mysql

cuento con 4 tablas las cuales necesito que me muestren la cantidad de material utilizado las tablas son inv_salidas, inv_salidas_list_mat las cuales están relacionadas con la clave de salida y inv__entradas, inv__entradas_list_mat las cuales están relacionadas con la clave de entrada ambas manejan materiales los cuales están vinculados por un numero de obra

ocupo la siguiente consulta para conocer la cantidad de materiales salidos de almacén ósea las salidas

```
SELECT 
  em.id_mat, 
  em.cve_mat, 
  em.mat, em.uni, 
  SUM(em.cant) AS total_salidas 
FROM inv_salidas e 
INNER JOIN inv_salidas_list_mat em ON e.clave = em.cve 
WHERE e.obra = 95 
GROUP BY em.id_mat,em.cve_mat, em.mat, em.uni  
ORDER BY em.id_mat ASC
```

esta me funciona correctamente asi como tambien manejo otra consulta similar para las entradas que ambas me arrojan resultados correctos en sus sumatorias

```
SELECT 
  am.id_mat, 
  am.cve, am.mat, 
  am.uni, SUM(am.cant) AS total_entradas 
FROM inv__entradas 
INNER JOIN inv__entradas_list_mat am ON am.cve_e = a.cve_entrada 
WHERE a.id_obra = 95 
GROUP BY am.id_mat, am.cve, am.mat, am.uni 
ORDER BY am.id_mat ASC
```

estas consultas las ocupo como control ya que se con certesa que me arrojan sumatorias correctas el problema es que al hacer una consulta comparativa para verificar las entradas y salidas las sumatorias no tienen nada que ver con la realidad y desconozco por que para ser claro hay algunos materiales que hay en salidas que no se encuentran en entradas ya que hay material que se toma de otras obras y por eso es necesario saber que salió de la obra que no pertenece o que no se considero inicialmente la siguiente consulta es la que esta generando problemas en las sumatorias

```
SELECT
  em.id_mat, 
  em.cve_mat, 
  em.mat, 
  em.uni, 
  SUM(em.cant) AS total_salidas, 
  SUM(am.cant_res) AS total_entradas 
FROM inv_salidas AS e 
INNER JOIN inv_salidas_list_mat AS em ON e.clave = em.cve 
LEFT JOIN inv__entradas AS a ON a.id_obra = e.obra 
LEFT JOIN inv__entradas_list_mat AS am ON am.cve_e = a.cve_entrada 
WHERE e.obra = 95 
GROUP BY em.id_mat, em.cve_mat, em.mat, em.uni 
ORDER BY em.id_mat ASC
```

espero puedan ayudarme ya que la verdad no entiendo donde esta el problema que me arroja sumatorias con números que nada que ver de antemano gracias por su tiempo.

Comment: Bueno.. ahora haces un join que nada que ver con los que hacias antes.. y no se te ocurrio, basicamente, olvidarte de tratar de mezclarlas, y simplemente joinearlas una con la otra, asi como estan????

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)!